# Validation Messages MVC 4

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I have a program made in MVC 4 with this model:

```
public class Component
    {
        public virtual int ComponentId { get; set; }

        public virtual string TypeComp { get; set; }
        public virtual string NameComp { get; set; }
        public virtual DateTime DateComp { get; set; }
    }
```

And the controller to create:

```
[HttpPost]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public ActionResult Create(Component component)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                db.Components.Add(component);
                db.SaveChanges();
                return RedirectToAction("Index");
            }

            return View(component);
        }
```

As you can see i have nothing here to make a field required. Also in the table all the variables are allowed to be null (except the id). But when i try to create, it always shows a message saying "field x is mandatory". If i remove this:

```
@Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.NomeComp)
```

from the create view, the message is hidden but it doesn't allow to create. My goal is to insert a field as null. What do I need to change? Thanks

Comment: Don't use EF Model objects as ViewModels.

Comment: Because its typeof `DateTime` which cannot be `null` - change the property to `DateTime?` if you want it to be nullable